# How can I interleave rows from 2 data frames together?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, interleave

How can I interleave rows from 2 data frames together like a perfect riffle shuffle?

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(df = 1, id = 1:5, chr = 'puppies')
df2 <- data.frame(df = 2, id = 1:5, chr = 'kitties')
```

df1:

```
  df id     chr
1  1  1 puppies
2  1  2 puppies
3  1  3 puppies
4  1  4 puppies
5  1  5 puppies
```

df2:

```
  df id     chr
1  2  1 kitties
2  2  2 kitties
3  2  3 kitties
4  2  4 kitties
5  2  5 kitties
```

Desired result:

```
      df    id     chr
1      1     1 puppies
2      2     1 kitties
3      1     2 puppies
4      2     2 kitties
5      1     3 puppies
6      2     3 kitties
7      1     4 puppies
8      2     4 kitties
9      1     5 puppies
10     2     5 kitties
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign row numbers to each data frame independently, then bind the rows and sort/arrange by row number and data frame id. In this example, row numbers are trivial since the ids are sequential and act as row number. But in the general case, row numbers should be used.

Here's an example using dplyr:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(row_number = row_number()) %>%
  bind_rows(df2 %>% mutate(row_number = row_number())) %>%
  arrange(row_number, df)
```

Output:

```
      df    id     chr row_number
   (dbl) (int)   (chr)      (int)
1      1     1 puppies          1
2      2     1 kitties          1
3      1     2 puppies          2
4      2     2 kitties          2
5      1     3 puppies          3
6      2     3 kitties          3
7      1     4 puppies          4
8      2     4 kitties          4
9      1     5 puppies          5
10     2     5 kitties          5
```

Answer (score 7):

A non-dplyr solution would be to use the [`interleave`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdata/versions/2.18.0/topics/interleave) function in the `gdata` package.

```
gdata::interleave(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R, I find that such manipulations are easier with matrices than with data.frames.
This quite lengthy one-liner should work:

```
setNames(data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(t(cbind(df1,df2))),ncol(df1)))),names(df1))
#   df id     chr
#1   1  1 puppies
#2   2  1 kitties
#3   1  2 puppies
#4   2  2 kitties
#5   1  3 puppies
#6   2  3 kitties
#7   1  4 puppies
#8   2  4 kitties
#9   1  5 puppies
#10  2  5 kitties
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R method that I believe works. There is a bit of setup cost. I also have to use character vectors rather than factors (stringsAsFactors=F)

```
# setup a blank data.frame of the proper dimensions
df <- data.frame(df=1:(nrow(df1) + nrow(df2)), 
                 id=1:(nrow(df1) + nrow(df2)),
                 chr=1:(nrow(df1) + nrow(df2)))

# fill it in with subscripting
df[1:(nrow(df1) + nrow(df2)) %% 2 == 1,] <- df1
df[1:(nrow(df1) + nrow(df2)) %% 2 == 0,] <- df2
df
   df id     chr
1   1  1 puppies
2   2  1 kitties
3   1  2 puppies
4   2  2 kitties
5   1  3 puppies
6   2  3 kitties
7   1  4 puppies
8   2  4 kitties
9   1  5 puppies
10  2  5 kitties
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(df = 1, id = 1:5, chr = 'puppies', stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(df = 2, id = 1:5, chr = 'kitties', stringsAsFactors=F)
```